# spring 3 Testing: issue with @Autowired -> can't load Context

Tags: spring-security, spring-test

I have following test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {
    "classpath:ApplicationContext.xml",
    "classpath:SecurityContext.xml"
})
public class CompoundServiceSecurityTest {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("testCompoundService")
    private TestCompoundService testCompoundService;

    //...
}
```

In this class, testCompoundService is autowired correctly and works (if the actual issue is "disabled"). The security context contains following custom class:

```
<bean id="testCompoundPermission"
      class="myPackage.TestCompoundPermission">
</bean>
```

and that class constains autowired testCompoundService:

```
public class TestCompoundPermission extends AbstractPermission {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("testCompoundService")
    private TestCompoundService testCompoundService;

    //...
}
```

The issue is that @Autowired testCompoundService in `TestCompoundPermission` fails with `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException` on a dependency of testCompoundService itself. `TestCompoundService` has a dependency on StructureService which has a dependency on StructureRepository (generated by Spring Data). Exception is:

```
NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type myApp.repository.StructureRepository found
```

If I comment `@Autowired` in `TestCompoundPermission` the Application context loads correctly (of course some test then fail with NullPointerException because testCompoundService is null).

This is weird because obviously on the test class the loading of the exact sane bean works perfectly fine. For completeness I also tried it with a constructor argument and removed @Autowired. Same Result. For me it looks like the 2 Contexts are completely separated and hence security context can't access beans from application-context. How can I solve this?

EDIT:

Last part of stacktrace (whole stack trace is huge!)

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'testCompoundService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private myApp.service.StructureService myApp.service.CompoundServiceImpl.StructureService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'StructureService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: myApp.repository.StructureRepository myApp.service.StructureServiceImpl.structureRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [myApp.repository.StructureRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:871)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:813)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:730)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:485)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private myApp.service.StructureService myApp.service.CompoundServiceImpl.StructureService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'StructureService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: myApp.repository.StructureRepository myApp.service.StructureServiceImpl.structureRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [myApp.repository.StructureRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:92)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:284)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'StructureService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: myApp.repository.StructureRepository myApp.service.StructureServiceImpl.structureRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [myApp.repository.StructureRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:871)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:813)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:730)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:485)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: myApp.repository.StructureRepository myApp.service.StructureServiceImpl.structureRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [myApp.repository.StructureRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:92)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:284)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [myApp.repository.StructureRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:947)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:816)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:730)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:485)
```

EDIT 2:

Found this:

http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?113720-No-matching-bean-when-using-custom-PermissionEvaluator-and-Spring-Data-JPA

Thats exactly the problem I have. However work-around does not work as `<jpa:repository />` is not a valid element anymore.

Comment: So do you have `myApp.repository.StructureRepository` bean or not?

Comment: Yes (see question). testCompoundService is autowired correctly in the test class but not in one of the classes used in the tests in that class.

Comment: Could you post stacktrace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this is a general issue with Spring data.

Please see

https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC-2136

for a complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is not the **problem with loading the configuration files**

It is the problem of **bean and its properties** that You defined in the xml files.

Check **.xml files** whether you have given the correct bean reference and its property reference used in the test class.

**Eg.)**

**testCompoundService Bean** must be defined in any of the **.XML that you invoke**